# Creating a DC resistor network matrix

Tags: resistors, dc, network, matrix

I have the following resistor network and I need to make a 7x7 matrix which would be the solution . I know the resistor values, but not the v1, v2, v3 or any of the current. I'm supposed to combine Kirchoff's Law with Ohm's Law to each resistor, but I'm not sure about how to actually create the matrix. If I have a 7x1 matrix of the unknowns, and rewrite them in terms on the resistor values, how do I then get to a 7x7 matrix?

[image]

Comment: Try starting off with only R1 and R4 in circuit. Write down the trivial equation for the vector of voltages as the resistive matrix times the current vector. Now add R2 and R5, rinse and repeat.

Comment: Would that be [R1 R4][I1] = [V0]? What I don't understand is how to solve the matrix for the 7 values if some are voltages and some are currents.

Comment: No, the dimensions of the vectors and matrix don't match. Read up some elementary vector/matrix algebra to get them to the right shape, and try again.

Comment: Oh yes, it would be: [R1 R4][I1] = [(V0 - v1) / (V1)] where '/' = new line. How then would I add R2 and R5 into it?

Comment: You use Kifchoffs at each node, for instance the v1 node, to express some currents as the sums of other currents. Note that this 'manual' way of combining currents half way through the solution is not the same as setting up the nodal matrix that simulators then invert to solve an arbitrary mesh, it's only practical for a very symmetrical circuit like this, but it does point you in the right direction, and ladder circuits do form a large sub-class of real world problems.

Answer (score 1):

Many (and I do mean many) years ago I remember being posed a similar problem. My maths tutor at that time revealed a wonderful (and very simple) way of solving such problems using **mesh current analysis.**

[image]

Each loop has a circular current (the direction is arbitary as the solution will decide the final direction - + value if its the same, - value if its opposite). Ohm's law is written in matrix form  [R]x[I] = [V]

*Now comes the elegant solution*.

For the voltage matrix simply write down the voltage in each loop , the loop currents are the unknown so simply write them down (i1, i2 etc)

The resistance matrix can be written by inspection -  current loop [1,1] contains r1+r2+3 - this is the first diagonal value. In the matrix positions [2,1 and 1,2] the common element between loop 1 and loop 2 is r2 but as the currents are in opposite directions this value is -r2. This continues with [2,2], [3,3] etc. Where there are no common elements the value is 0.

You could mutliply out the matrix to get a set of simultaneous equations with seven unknowns (i1 to i7) eg

(r1+r2+r3)i1 -r2i2  = V1

-r2i1  + (r4+r5+r6+r2)i2 -r5i3  = 0

or solve the matrix using a computer.

Once you have the mesh current values (i1 to i7) then you can easily convert them into voltage and current circuit values around the circuit by applying kirchoff and ohm's law.

e.g The current through r2 is (i1 -i2), the voltage across r2, Vr2 = r2 x (i1-i2)

Additional edit:

In your circuit the method is applied thus:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you, but in my question there are only 3 loops. I can get 4 equations, 3 being from the loop method, but with voltages; and the fourth from KCL. It's the last three equations I'm not able to get.

Comment: @GeraltOfMordor Have added your specific problem to demonstrate how to apply this method

Comment: That's how I got 3 of the equations. The fourth being I0 - I2 - I3 -I4 = 0. The question specifically asks for a 7x7 matrix though.

Comment: @GeraltOfMordor  There is no variable I0 but i1, by kirchoff, would equal the summ of the other currents

Comment: Oh yes, that was a mistake.Yes, but how do I get three equations for the voltages from it?

Comment: @GeraltOfMordor If you know the currents (i1 to i4) then V1 = i2 x R4, V2 =i3 x R5 and V3 = i4 x R6  (simple Ohm's law)

Comment: Yes, of course, but the question specifies to make a 7x7 matrix to be solved via Matlab. So I need 7 equations which include the 7 unknowns. As I've said, I have 4 equations which include the unknown current values, I'm just not sure how to get the voltage equations.

Answer (score 0):

The common way being taught is to take shortcuts when doing either loop or node analysis by incorporating ohms law. For example, using node analysis in the typical way will give you 3 equations and 3 unknowns (v1, v2, v3). Given v1, v2, v3, then you can go back and solve for any current.

If I understand the question correctly, you have to use the 7 assigned variables in a matrix. So one way to do that is to write the equations for node analysis, which give you 3 equations based on KCL. Then use ohms law to write 3 equations for R4, R5, R6. Then use KVL and write one equation for R1.

With that, you have 7 equations and 7 variables as assigned on the diagram. Form that into a matrix and solve that.

What you would find is that, the matrix contains a submatrix. The key to solving it manually would be the submatrix from the first 3 KCL equations of node analysis.

This is an unnecessarily convoluted approach.

Comment: I have 3 equations from applying KVL to each mesh, I have one from KCL. Isn't there only one from using KCL, I1 = I2 + I3 + I4? Where do I get the other 3 from?

Comment: Once again, if I understand the question correctly, it wants you to solve for the 7 variables in the diagram all in one matrix equation. The 7 variables are (i1, i2, i3, i4, v1, v2, v3). It sounds like you have gotten 4 equations with i1, i2, i3, i4. Then add 3 more to introduce v1, v2, v3 using ohm's law such as i2 * R4 = v1, etc.

Comment: Yes, but that's where I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to get the voltage equations.

Comment: The simplest way to get v1, v2, v3 would be the v1 = i2 * r4, v2 = i3 * r6, v3 = i4 * r7.